# How to download or fetch a file from Project directory using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a html table created manually using JQuery, when the user click on row that calls a Jquery Ajax function. This function calls a ASP.NET MVC Controller, the Controller call internally fetching the file from File Server and storing into Project Directory under folder "..\download\". 
I need to return this file JQuery and downloadable file in a Browser.

Calling API and store the file(any type) in the Project Directory:

```
var response = _httpClient.GetAsync(documentURL).Result;
HttpContent content = response.Content;
string currfile = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(string.Format("~/download/"));
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(currfile);
foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
{
    file.Delete();
}
using (var file = new FileStream(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(string.Format("~/download/{0}.{1}", fileName, fileExt)), FileMode.CreateNew))
{ // create a new file to write to
    Stream contentStream = content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result; // get the actual content stream                
    contentStream.CopyToAsync(file); // copy that stream to the file stream
    file.FlushAsync(); // flush back to disk before disposing
}
```

**JQuery Call**:

```
$("#DivAttachmentDetails  tr:not(:first)").click(function () {
    var DocumentumId = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").find(':input[name=hdnDocumentumId]').val();//$('#hdnDocumentumId').val();        
         $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: getExactPath('/Supplier/GetDocument'),
              data: {
                  documetObj: DocumentumId
              },
              dataType: 'json',
              async: false,
                  success: function (jsonData) {                              
              },
              error: function () {
                  alert("Unable to fetch the Document.");
              }
             });
             });
```

How do i get this file immediately back to the Browser using JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the file into "..\download\filename.pdf", i am sending back the concatenate foldername + filename . I am storing in a solution directory folder since the page usage is less than 5 users.

```
string returnurl:
using (var file = new FileStream(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(string.Format("~/download/{0}.{1}", fileName, fileExt)), FileMode.CreateNew))
{ // create a new file to write to
    Stream contentStream = content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result; // get the actual content stream                
    contentStream.CopyToAsync(file); // copy that stream to the file stream
    file.FlushAsync(); // flush back to disk before disposing

    returnurl =  "\download\"+ fileName+"."+fileExt
}
```

JQuery:

```
success: function (jsonData) 
{                              
    window.open(jsonData.returnurl) // this opens the file in new windows as "http:\\projectname:8080\download\yourfilename.pdf" ( any file type)
},
```